# Creating a Stored Procedure from Inside ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

One of the requirements for an ASP.NET MVC (3) app I'm working on is that it must be able to create and populate all required database tables, etc. if it's configured to use an empty database.

Since it's a standard ASP.NET MVC3 app, it uses the standard authentication tables (`aspnet_*`), along with a bunch of stored procedures and stuff.

What I'm trying right now is creating the tables through migrations (via MigratorDotNet) one by one as necessary (so far only made the `aspnet_Users` one), hoping they're not all needed; other stuff I'll need includes certain stored procedures, like `CheckSchemaVersion`.

**How can I create these from *inside* an ASP.NET MVC app?**

I also have a SQL dump of an empty ASP.NET MVC database (so it creates all the tables and stored procedures) to extract the relevant SQL from. As a super last resort, if I can somehow run this from inside my app, that may suffice as a solution.

If it matters, I'm using ActiveRecord (backed by NHibernate) with SQL Server 2008 Express .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed possible. The code is available in my application, [Syzite](http://syzite.com), which is open-source (check `AdminController.createAspNetStoredProcedures()`).

The solution was to:

- Store the procedures into a text file on the server
- Iterate over all the lines
- Find every set of `CREATE PROCEDURE ... )\n` as a procedure generation call
- Create a `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` instance
- Call `instance.ExecuteCommand` with the `CREATE PROCEDURE` code.